# Microsoft CRM Multiple Lines of Text field issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-4

I have a form with 3 fields with datatype Multiple lines of Text. I've been asked to display the complete content even if the entered text values are long for these 3 fields.

So i went ahead and checked the `Automatically expand to use available space` from the field format section in the form editor for each of these 3 fields.

[image]

But, it seems that CRM would only allow only one of these fields to have this `Automatically expand to use available space`  property checked and this is how the form looks now -

[image]

In the above image, the fields Co-insurance, Reinsurance and Activity Record are all multiple lines of text.

Any help to expand all the fields to occupy their available text spaces on the form will be highly appreciated. Please note that the page should display only a single line of text on page load.

Thanks in advance.
FYI - I am using Microsoft CRM 2016 online instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is currently only possible to set *Automatically expand to use available space* on one multi-line text field per tab.

Your only supported option is thus to place the multi-line text fields in separate tabs, if you want to use the auto-expand functionality.

There is a suggestion on Connect, [Allow multiple multiline textboxes to auto expand per tab](https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedbackdetail/view/2010216/allow-multiple-multiline-textboxes-to-auto-expand-per-tab), that you can upvote to have this changed:

> With the CRM 2013 SP 1 UR 3 release, Microsoft fixed an issue with
>   “Automatically expand to use available space” property on a multiline
>   textbox when the properties box was not checked. Our users liked the
>   feature (1000+ user base), so we thought we could go into our forms
>   and just check the property box to “Automatically expand to use
>   available space”. However, there seems to be a limitation on the
>   number of multiline textbox per tab. You can only set the property on
>   one multiline textbox per tab.
>
> We would like to see if MS could allow us to set this property on as
>   many multiline textboxes we want in one tab.